# Is this review test post high quality or not?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Had this audit popup today. I chose 'No action' and it says I have successfully passed the test.

[image]

However, first comment in the post from a user states that the post should be marked as off-topic.

So which is it? Is it a high quality post or should it be marked as off-topic?

Would like to know so I can learn more about the rules to improve my reviews.

Comment: You should actually link to the audit, not a picture of the audit.

Comment: @Servy there it is: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16141759

Comment: Meh. Its definitely not high quality, but it seems a valid question. Its just a weird assumption in the text, not all questions which are on-topic are high quality. It should probably say something along the lines of "this question meets at least the minimal quality standards".